# Best Practice: Secondary Index In DBMS

Tags: database

I am very new to DBMS, so the question i am asking might be trivial. I couldn't get answers from google so i am asking it here.

What is a good practice when choosing a secondary index for a table?

The choices are:

1. Index a column that is frequently updated
2. Index a columns that consists of long character Strings
3. Index a foreign key that is frequently accessed
4. Index a column with few (< 5) different values

Comment: Can you include a description of your table and the sort of queries you plan on doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. This was a question given to me. There is no mentioning of table or queries

Comment: Fair enough.  I asked because your question might have left open the possibility that you don't need a second index.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see. So is there a way to solve this, given the choices my teacher gave me